# Tensor Dimensions must be equal

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am writing my own code for False alarm metrics in Keras for Neural networks. The Neural network implemented gives an output of (100,1) dimension, where each output value is between 0 and 1. The batch size is 1000. In the false_alarm1 function, I want to select the top k probabilities and make them 1 and the rest equal to 0 and then calculate the confusion matrix. I received a message that the dimensions do not match. I tried all the solutions available on the internet for a similar problem but nothing seems to work.

Here is the function, I implemented

```
def false_alarm1(y_true, y_pred): #based on the Top K probabilities

values , indices =tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k =2)
topk_value = tf.math.argmin(input = values, axis =-1)
topk_value = tf.broadcast_to(topk_value , shape = tf.shape(y_pred))
topk_value = K.cast(topk_value, K.floatx())
y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, K.floatx())
y_pred = K.greater_equal(y_pred , topk_value)
y_pred = K.cast(y_pred, K.floatx())
y_true = K.cast(y_true, K.floatx())
a = K.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
b = K.reshape(y_true, [-1])
conf = tf.math.confusion_matrix(b, a)/tf.shape(a)[0]
score1 = conf[0][1]/(conf[0][0] + conf[0][1])
return score1
```

I also tried this

```
topk_value = tf.broadcast_to(topk_value , shape = (1000,100))
```

The progress of the NN

```
Train on 8000 samples

1000/8000 [==>...........................] - ETA: 5s
```

The error I received

```
InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1000 and 100 for 'metrics/false_alarm1/BroadcastTo' (op: 'BroadcastTo') with input shapes: [1000], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1000,100].

ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 1000 and 100 for 'metrics/false_alarm1/BroadcastTo' (op: 'BroadcastTo') with input shapes: [1000], [2] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [1000,100].
```

My Model:

```
    __________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 140)]        0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 1000)         141000      input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization (BatchNorma (None, 1000)         4000        dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (BatchNor (None, 1000)         4000        dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu (ReLU)                    (None, 1000)         0           batch_normalization_1[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)               (None, 1000)         0           re_lu[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add (Add)                       (None, 1000)         0           dropout[0][0]                    
                                                                 batch_normalization[0][0]        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (BatchNor (None, 1000)         4000        dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_1 (ReLU)                  (None, 1000)         0           batch_normalization_2[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)             (None, 1000)         0           re_lu_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_1 (Add)                     (None, 1000)         0           dropout_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 add[0][0]                        
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (BatchNor (None, 1000)         4000        dense_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_2 (ReLU)                  (None, 1000)         0           batch_normalization_3[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)             (None, 1000)         0           re_lu_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_2 (Add)                     (None, 1000)         0           dropout_2[0][0]                  
                                                                 add_1[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (BatchNor (None, 1000)         4000        dense_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_3 (ReLU)                  (None, 1000)         0           batch_normalization_4[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, 1000)         0           re_lu_3[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_3 (Add)                     (None, 1000)         0           dropout_3[0][0]                  
                                                                 add_2[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (BatchNor (None, 1000)         4000        dense_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_4 (ReLU)                  (None, 1000)         0           batch_normalization_5[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)             (None, 1000)         0           re_lu_4[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_4 (Add)                     (None, 1000)         0           dropout_4[0][0]                  
                                                                 add_3[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)                 (None, 1000)         1001000     add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (BatchNor (None, 1000)         4000        dense_6[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
re_lu_5 (ReLU)                  (None, 1000)         0           batch_normalization_6[0][0]      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)             (None, 1000)         0           re_lu_5[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
add_5 (Add)                     (None, 1000)         0           dropout_5[0][0]                  
                                                                 add_4[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)                 (None, 100)          100100      add_5[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_Sigmoid (TensorFlow (None, 100)          0           dense_7[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
```

Comment: Could you post your model?

Comment: @AloneTogether I added the model as you requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update` to make the top-k probabilities 1 and the rest 0:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_true = [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 0]]
y_pred = [[0.7, 0.5, 0.94, 0.01], [0.3, 0.1, 0.33, 0.41]]

def false_alarm1(y_true, y_pred): 
  k = 2
  new_y_pred = tf.zeros_like(y_pred)
  _ , indices = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k = k)
  batch_indices = tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(y_pred)[0]), repeats=k)
  indices = tf.stack([batch_indices, tf.reshape(indices,[-1])], axis=1)
  new_y_pred = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(new_y_pred, indices, tf.ones(tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(indices)[0])))
  print(new_y_pred)

  return tf.math.confusion_matrix(tf.reshape(y_true,[-1]), tf.reshape(new_y_pred,[-1]))

print(false_alarm1(y_true, y_pred))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[2 3]
 [2 1]], shape=(2, 2), dtype=int32)
```

And your original implementation with the changes would look like this:

```py
def false_alarm1(y_true, y_pred): 
  k = 2
  new_y_pred = tf.zeros_like(y_pred)
  _ , indices = tf.math.top_k(y_pred, k = k)
  batch_indices = tf.repeat(tf.range(tf.shape(y_pred)[0]), repeats=k)
  indices = tf.stack([batch_indices, tf.reshape(indices,[-1])], axis=1)
  new_y_pred = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(new_y_pred, indices, tf.ones(tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(indices)[0])))

  a = tf.reshape(new_y_pred,[-1])
  b = tf.reshape(y_true,[-1])
  conf = tf.math.confusion_matrix(b, a)/tf.shape(a)[0]
  score1 = conf[0][1]/(conf[0][0] + conf[0][1])
  return score1
```

Comment: yes it did solve my problem. Thanks a lot!